# How to optimize code with kotlin coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Here is my code for each item I open new coroutine ,but the problem is that I want to optimize it and do some limitation let's say to have 5 coroutines , I know there is a solution with Coroutines Action ,but I don't know how can I introduce them here. Any help could be useful

```
  uiScope.launch {
        val infoItem = fetchItems(item.query)
        infoItems.add(infoItem)
        itemsMutableData.postValue(infoItems)
      }
  }

  override suspend fun fetchItems(query: String): Response<List<Item>>{
    return suspendCoroutine {})
    }
  }
```

Comment: `infoItems` sounds unsafe and you should not have that dingling around.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce what do you mean?

Comment: S/he means that you may have concurrent access to that object. Race conditions can corrupt memory and create hard-to-reproduce bugs.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce those coroutines run in the UI thread, that serializes the accesses. From the code we see (which does not even compile) it is safe.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I guessed your question right. You have a bunch of `Stuff`, and have to do an async call for every one of them. Creating a coroutine for each of them works fine.

```
val stuffList: List<Stuff> = ...
stuffList.map {
    launch {
        process(it)
    }
}.joinAll()
```

But this piece of code starts a lot of requests all at once. So you want to limit the concurrency, maybe at most 5 concurrent calls.

The "best" pattern for it is still [an open issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/172) on github.
You should take a look at their ideas.

---

For now you can use a naive implementation.

- Create a work `Channel`, send the stuff to it and then close it.
- `launch` n coroutines that `receive` from it and process the `Stuff` until reaching `ClosedReceiveChannelException`.
- `join` the coroutines.